# Size of array has non-integral type when using c++11 enum class

Tags: c++11, enums

I used this code:

```
enum E {
    E1, E2, E3, MaxNum
};

const char * ENames[ MaxNum ] = {
    "E1", "E2", "E3"
};
```

and had no problem.
Now I want to use "modern" `enum class`. The code now looks like this:

```
enum class E {
    E1, E2, E3, MaxNum
};

const char * ENames[ E::MaxNum ] = {
    "E1", "E2", "E3"
};
```

and got an error

> error: size of array ‘ENames’ has non-integral type ‘E’
>
> error: too many initializers for ‘const char* [1]’

Q: why `enum class` does become non-integral in c++11, while usual enum is integral ?

What is a decision of a problem ? How can I declare an array with size, that is one of enumeration in `enum class` ?

Here - http://ideone.com/SNHTYe - is a simple example.

Thank you.

Comment: You can cast it to the underlying type `const char * ENames[static_cast<typename std::underlying_type<E>::type>(E::MaxNum)] = {"E1", "E2", "E3"};`

Comment: @user2523017 thank you. I didn't know about `underlying_type`. I think, you should make it as an answer

Comment: I don’t understand your “why” question: surely *the whole point* of enum classes is that they are a distinct type that isn’t implicitly convertible. Now, whether this is really practical is a whole different question. IMHO C++11 enum classes are pretty useless.

Comment: @KonradRudolph you're right, but this is my first look at `enum class`, and I did't know (till now) all details about  implicit/explicit convertions to/from them

Comment: I didn't make it an answer because it only addresses parts of your question and I am not familiar with the complete design rationale behind scoped & strongly-typed enums. Feel free to use it in your answers, though!

Comment: a usual enum is *not* an integral type. the error message is a bit confusing.

Answer (score 7):

> Q: why `enum class` does become non-integral in c++11, while usual enum is integral ?

Because it's not a "usual enum", it's more strongly-typed

> How can I declare an array with size, that is one of enumeration in enum class ?

Why do you want to anyway?  You could use a `static_cast` but the solution to your problem is "don't do that".

If you want an enum of fixed underlying type then do that, don't use a scoped enum:

```
enum E : uint16_t {
    E1, E2, E3, MaxNum
};

const char * ENames[ MaxNum ] = {
    "E1", "E2", "E3"
};
```

Comment: +1 Never realized the underlying type could be specified and the `enum` remain unscoped.

Comment: Every day (to speek correctly - hour) I'm learning something new... I thought, that specifying an underlying type is possible only for scoped enums (aka enum class). Thank you. /me goes to learn standard about enums ))

Answer (score 5):

C++11 5.19/3 "Constant expressions"

> An integral constant expression is a literal constant expression of integral or **unscoped** enumeration type.

Scoped enumerations are not integral constant expressions. And an array dimension (if specified) must be "an integral constant expression and its value shall be greater than zero" (8.3.4/1 "Arrays").

I suspect that the rationale for this is that scoped enums do not implicitly convert to `int`.

To work around the problem, you could static cast the scoped enum to an `int` as suggested by user2523017, or use the pre-C++11 methods of scoping enum names:

```
namespace E {
enum {
      E1, E2, E3, MaxNum
    };
}
```

or:

```
struct E {
enum {
      E1, E2, E3, MaxNum
    };
};
```

Comment: Thank you for standard's quots, for explanation about implicity convertion, and for trying to resolve the problem, but I don't want to use pre-C++11 methods, because I want to specify a type for my enum: `enum class E : uint16_t` for example

Comment: @borisbn, you don't need to use a scoped enum to have a fixed underlying type, just write `enum E : uint16_t`